# Refresh field list not adding some unindexed fields in Kibana

Tags: kibana

I am new to Kibana, and I am having problems relating to filtering my logs.

Several of the fields in my logs cannot be filtered (for example, "statusCode". They do not appear in the dropdown when selecting a filter, and when I refresh the Index Patterns page under Management, they still do not appear.

These fields *do* appear under "available fields" and I can display them as columns. They also appear in the dropdown table under each item (with an icon saying "no cached mapping for this field"), but if I click on the "filter for field present" button, I get an empty list.

Every suggestion I have seen so far just says "go to Index Patterns and click the refresh button" but that isn't working. Is it possible to manually add these missing fields?

Answer (score 0):

Do the following steps

1. Go to "Settings" then "Index Patterns" and select the index, click on refresh you should be able to see all the fields available in the table below
2. Use the filter to find required field, click on edit icon and change the format from Default to the actual format of the type
3. Change the popularity to a number may be 1 or 2 as required. This number helps to show fields on top

Save and you are good to go. Screenshot below
[image]